# npx react-native run-android error Unrecognized command "run-android"

Tags: react-native, npm-install, npx

I'm rather new to the whole RN world, my project ran just fine, but after I added a library (npm install)
I get this error

> Unrecognized command "run-android".

When I do

```
npx react-native run-android
```

From a lot of readings about it what I tried so far is

1. npm uninstall -> npm install
2. delete node modules folder -> npm install
3. delete node modules -> delete package.json.lock-> npm install
4. npx react-native link

All didn't help , any ideas on how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the run-android command by running below command

> npm i react-native-run-android